# XSLT-2.0: Output to file

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

Using SaxonHE 9.7/XPath-2.0

Why is this identity template returning a "Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI" when it's output is sent to a file? Without `xsl:result-document` it sends it to the standard out as expected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:result-document href="Output.xml">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="Output.xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the normal identity transformation template, that way the output created by the stylesheet goes to `Output.xml`. Your current code matches any node and for each matched node tries to open the same file, that is not allowed.